# Presenting a modal view controller with cross-disolve isn't showing views added in code

Tags: objective-c, ipad, modalviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

When I present a modal view controller over my view storyboard originated root view controller it flashes the story board view, even if it has been altered.  My root view controller has a bright green back ground with large white subview across the top that contains a label bound to an IBOutlet.  In UIViewController viewDidLoad I am adding a light gray, slightly transparent UIView that covers the entire view as a subview of the viewcontroller's view. I am also setting the label text to be different than that of the Storyboard layout.

When I trigger the modal, either via segue or via presentViewController:completion: what I see is the light gray view over my label then the view added in code seems to become transparent and animate away and the bright green of the storyboard layout shows up and then the modal view cross-dissolves in.  When I dismiss the first and present the second in the completion block i see a cross-dissolve to bright green, pop of light as the added view becomes visible again, pop to bright green and the cross-dissolve in of the second view controller's view.

When I dismiss the second view controller then I see cross-dissolve out to the bright green and then the added light gray, semi-transparent view pops back to being visible.

***Anyone have any idea how to stop the cross-dissolve from showing the views underneath the view added in code?***

This example is made more jarring if you remove the opacity from the overlay view added in viewDidLoad.

https://github.com/jonnolen/ios-cross-disolve-problem

Code snippet and story board layout:

[image]

```
@interface DTViewController (){
    BOOL hasShownSegue;
}

@end

@implementation DTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView * view = [UIView new];

    view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:.95 alpha:.7];

    NSLog(@"View Bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));

    [self.view addSubview:view];
    self.label.text = @"Hello!";
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (!hasShownSegue){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modal.1.segue" sender:self];
        hasShownSegue = YES;
    }
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    DTCallbackViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;

    vc.completionCallback = ^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            DTCallbackViewController * vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc.2"];

            vc.completionCallback = ^{
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            };

            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

        }];
    };
}
```

Comment: You describe what you're seeing, but it's not at all clear from your question what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I don't really like it but it works:

I put all of the maskable content into a separate view:

[image]

And then hide that view when I need it to be "masked".

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"View Bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
    self.label.text = @"Hello!";
    self.content.hidden = YES;
}
```

Then animations behave as expected.  However, this only works with an opaque mask (which is what I needed).